# Why is the oneric-backport repository enable by default on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, repository

I installed Xubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 11.10 in both the oneric-backport is enabled by default.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Canonical's decision? Uncomment it if you don't like it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a decision they made to help people get the best drivers for their systems. There was a bug created here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/840135

And here was the spec discussion:

- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-o-backports-bof

And here is the quote from [the release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes):

> ### Backports are now more easily accessible
>
> To enable users to more easily receive new versions of software, the Ubuntu Backports repository is now enabled by default. Packages from backports will not be installed by default — they must explicitly be selected in package management software. However, once installed, packages from backports will automatically be upgraded to newer versions.